# After various attempts to push through, this BTC transaction is taking forever to confirm?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I have lodged it with ViaBTC for acceleration and yet no joy on it...Can anybody tell me what you think the issue is with this one?

b451ebd0ba7ff7b4d75117a3fd6a64a8e42b82da0135a03ed73fdc6bf4d52cf4

It is a transaction that I withdrew from Trady.io.

Suggestions....or can anyone potentially push through...as I have no idea what to do next?

Thanks!

Comment: It got confirmed. Your problem is solved.

Comment: It got confirmed. You can see it at https://blockchain.info/tx/b451ebd0ba7ff7b4d75117a3fd6a64a8e42b82da0135a03ed73fdc6bf4d52cf4. Add a higher fee to have it confirmed faster.

Answer (score 1):

You may pay a higher fee when you make a btc transfer. For instant in blockchain.info you can set it to fast transfer now!